# Why is Glade 3.19 missing in xUbuntu Wily?

Tags: 15.10, glade

I've noticed that Glade v3.19 is missing in the Ubuntu Wily repositories. Is there a reason for this? Or, is there a way I can install Glade 3.19 or do I just have to wait until Xenial to come out?

Comment: The repos tend to have the most stable version, not the latest and there site says "Glade 3.19.0 is the first development release in the series." So that's why it is not in the repos. Also under this launchpad page it seems Xenial will also get 3.18.3-1  not 3.19 https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glade Why not build it your self ?

Comment: I'll try , but I would not want to mess with dependencies

Comment: I tried to build this from source but faced an bug in `autogen` I can't seem to fix.

Answer (score 1):

That's because Ubuntu is not a rolling distro.

Xenail would not help, since [Glade is at version 3.18.3-1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=glade&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all) there.

Please note that Glade 3.19 is **not** stable, it is a development version, as you can [see in the announcement](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/glade-devel/2015-June/002090.html).

EDIT: please note also that, if their release cycle follows Gnome standards, then the stable versions are with even numbers (3.14, 3.16, 3.18) while development versions are with odd numbers (3.17, 3.19, ...) so probably 3.19 will never see the light in Ubuntu; the next one will be 3.20.

Comment: @Andrea70 if this answer answers your question, why do not accept it? :)